# Feature Suggestion - "Did you forget?"

Tags: feature-request, email, reminder

I have a suggestion for a feature to help out those of us with bad memories.  Can a daemon be created to skim through the questions that have been asked, but the OP has apparently forgotten it, so no answer was accepted, and nothing was acknowledged by the OP?  Basically, if I post a question, log out (since i don't expect an answer in the next 5 minutes, like I would in a chatroom), and forget about that question, can an email be automatically sent to me 15, 20, or 30 days later asking "Hey, you have some answers here, did you forget about this?" (choose your phrasing).  Thanks

Comment: Well, that would be obnoxious! What if I didn't forget, I just hadn't checked on the question?

Comment: AFAIK, this is already exists

Comment: I agree with @TheEstablishment, this would be terribly obnoxious. What if the answers posted just aren't relevant or do not actually answer the question? You'd have to have a way to opt specific questions out of the notifications... just sounds like a lot of work for very little benefit.

Comment: Besides, it's a solution in search of a problem. Do you *really* think there are that many people who ask questions that they completely forget about?

Comment: And to that end, if you're asking questions that aren't important enough for you to remember then why did you bother wasting the community's time?

Comment: If you have trouble remembering just subscribe to the feed like this one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/127614

Comment: He must have forgotten about this one...

Comment: NO BECAUSE YOU SHOULD BE ON THE SITE EVERYDAY WHAT IS WRONG WITH YOU

Comment: Just don't forget. Write it down ,etc

Comment: Please don't log out immediately after asking a question. Stick around for a little while to answer questions in comments from those of us riding the FGITW wave.

Comment: Well, I can understand the desire not to receive spam, my thought was more of a voluntary opt-in if I go to say, bicycles se, put in a question, and then don't remember to go back.  I'm not on bicycles regularly (don't have my account active for that one), so it would be easy for me to forget.  Also, I was thinking of it as the system monitors and detects if the op returns to the question or not within the time period.  So this change would be SE wide, but those who use it would have to specifically opt in, it would be turned off by default, so we don't get daily emails we may not want.

Answer (score 4):

No thank you.  I would not like spam from SE going "AAHH!  You haven't accepted an answer!!!1!!one" when none of the answers helped.

However, if you really want it, we have something similar:

[image]

Comment: Huh. I never noticed that before. Ever. No big loss, though. I don't need more spam in my inbox...